# Load image from photo library

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, photo

1. How can I load an image from photo library and show it in **imageView**?
2. How can I change image to **black and white**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert image form `UIImagePickerController` to black and white you can use this code:

```
UIImage *originalImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; // this image we get from UIImagePickerController

CGColorSpaceRef colorSapce = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height, 8, originalImage.size.width, colorSapce, kCGImageAlphaNone);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, NO);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, originalImage.size.width, originalImage.size.height), [originalImage CGImage]);

CGImageRef bwImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CGContextRelease(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSapce);

UIImage *resultImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:bwImage]; // This is result B/W image.
CGImageRelease(bwImage);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to load an image from photo library, you have to use UIImagePickerController class. [Refer this Link](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)