# Load image from the iPhone library

Tags: objective-c, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Load image from photo library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333652/load-image-from-photo-library)

How do I create a function to load an image from the iPhone library, and how would I be able to load it into a variable (get the URL/path of the image)?

Comment: Do you mean the system photo albums, such as the camera roll? The API for having the user select a photo from an album is called UIImagePickerController.

Comment: You need to spend more time with the documentation provided by Apple before writing another line of code.

Comment: @philip, if you are not going to be helpful, then dont waste your time and comment here... you are just wasting your own time!!!

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a low-level support site to answer questions that are easily found in freely available documentation. It is for high quality questions to get high quality answers from expert, knowledgeable users that go beyond the norm. As you spend more time in the community, you will come to understand this. It is not my time being wasted, but rather yours and I am trying to prevent that by giving you the feedback you need to make the most of your time spent here.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `UIImagePickerController`,

```
UIImagePickerController *pickerLibrary = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerLibrary.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
pickerLibrary.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:pickerLibrary animated:YES];
```

and a delegate method to get select image from the gallery,

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    UIImage *myImage = image;
}
```

Hope it gives you an idea...

Comment: @Maulik - thanks, it opened my library correctly but after selecting a perticular image my delegate method doesn't get called even i added both the delegates (UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate)

Answer (score 2):

Because the photo library may contain personal images, the only way to access it is via user interaction.

You will need to use the `UIImagerPickerController` which will display an interface allowing the user to pick an image from their Camera Roll, Photo Library or even take a picture or video using the camera.

Read the docs for the `UIImagePickerController` and learn how to use it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html